# Webpack Sequential Multiple Configs?

Tags: webpack

I have a single file `webpack.dev.js` and within it I have 2 standard build configs.

```
const buildA = {};
const buildB = {};

module.exports = [buildA, buildB];
```

This is sweet, everything works.  The problem is however that `buildB` expects `buildA` to complete and the builds appear to occur in parallel.  So I get an error.

Is there a way to achieve sequential builds when using this format?  Otherwise, how could I achieve something similar by another means?

I am using `webpack-dev-server` which appears to only take a single configuration and that is why I am down this path of multiple configurations exported

Answer (score 0):

there's a discussion at Github (ref https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3838, https://www.viget.com/articles/run-multiple-webpack-configs-sequentially/) will try it in a bit.

the plugin was trying to poll and wait for a certain file to be available before resuming the next config in line.